# Make blank tex file handle PyLatex

Tags: python, inheritance, latex, pylatex

I want to make a blank tex file in PyLatex with no headers and no environments added from the start. i.e. I do not want `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` to be in my LaTex file. I've tried to write a class that does not propagate any packages or adds anything to the file in the beginning, but I can no longer add my commands to the file afterward.

```
\cvsection{}
\begin{cventries}
    
  \cventry
    {}
    {}
    {}
    {}
    {}
    \vspace{5mm} 
\end{cventries}
```

But every I've tried to use the `Document` class, PyLatex adds the `\begin{document}` and `\documentclass` preamble. This is the minimum I've been able to achieve:

```
\documentclass
%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\end{document}
```

I only need a simple blank tex file where I can add 1 command `cvsection` and 1 environment `cventries`.

This was the dumps method in my class:

```
def dumps(self):
    head = ''
    print("No headers")
    head += dumps_list(self.variables) + '%\n'
    head += dumps_list(self.preamble) + '%\n'
    return head + '%\n' + super(ArgFreeDoc, self).dumps()
```

This still has the same output as the `Document` class. If I remove the super method in the return statement, I can't add new text to my file.

TLDR; How do I generate a blank tex file class and add commands to it after that?